# webservice returns SID - how do I store result as an integer?

Tags: java, android, web-services, ksoap2

First off, I am rather a development novice so this is probably a basic question

Heres my current code to return response from a login method.

```
SoapPrimitive result =(SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
String Something = result.toString();
```

Something is a session id and so I need to store it as an integer but I don't know how to store it as an int - something like this:

```
SoapPrimitive result =(SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
int Something = result;
```

But it doesn't work. **How do I store it as an integer?**

If there's any way to improve my question let me know rather than just marking me down.
Thankyou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
String Something = result.toString(); 
int intResult = Integer.parseInt(Something);
```